# Data Distribution - Scenario

Tags: excel

This may be complex to do in Excel (I think), but I have a spreadsheet like this:

[image]

What I need to do:

The A, B, C and D have some specific values, as you can see in the colum C.
The total of them will always be 44, it does not change.

Below I have a table with the weekdays. I need to distribute these values following these 5 conditions:

1) The total per day (line 13th) cannot exceed 10.

2) The total per line (column H) cannot exceed the values indicated above in the small table, so for example, if the value of A is 2.2, the total of the line cannot exceed it.

3) The cell G:15 is just sum of everything, that must be 44, not more, not less.

4) The values cannot have 2 or more decimal, it can have only 1 decimals, like 1.0, 1.5 etc ... it cannot be like 1.55, 1.72 etc.

5) The line does not need to have values in all columns. Example: If A has the value of 2.2, I can distribute 1.1 on Monday and 1.1 on Tuesday, the other days of the week is OK to be empty.

Here is an example of the values filled:

[image]

Is it too complex? If so, no problem, just wondering if I can automate this distribution without doing manually, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I could do it with an Excel add-in called Solver, using the conditions below:

[image]